# MySql query to perform join between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

These are the tables:

```
professor
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| empid | name   | status | salary | age  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|     1 | Arun   |      1 |   2000 |   23 |
|     2 | Benoy  |      0 |   3000 |   25 |
|     3 | Chacko |      1 |   1000 |   36 |
|     4 | Divin  |      0 |   5000 |   32 |
|     5 | Edwin  |      1 |   2500 |   55 |
|     7 | George |      0 |   1500 |   46 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+

works
+----------+-------+---------+
| courseid | empid | classid |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |     1 |      10 |
|        2 |     2 |       9 |
|        3 |     3 |       8 |
|        4 |     4 |      10 |
|        5 |     5 |       9 |
|        6 |     1 |       9 |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

The above are the tables from which I need to retrieve the data from.

> The question is to return list of Employees who take both Class 10 and
>   Class 9.

The query I have written is:

```
select professor.name 
from inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
where works.classid=9 and works.classid=10;
```

I know that the result I want is `Arun`, but I don't know what should be the exact query to retrieve the required result.

Comment: what your query is returning?

Comment: Its returning empty set. I know that the query I tried is incorrect. I dont know how to perform it. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He wants the professeors that take class 9 AND 10. So there are 2 different records in works that need to match.

```
select professor.name from  professor
join works A on A.empid=professor.empid and A.classid=9
join works B on B.empid=professor.empid and B.classid=10
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be88a/1

Comment: This gives me the required result. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thanks again for that website link :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select professor.name 
from professor inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
where works.classid=9 OR works.classid=10;
```

(OR)

```
select professor.name 
from professor inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
where works.classid IN ('9','10')
```

Comment: Your first query is same as Francis S and second query IN will not work as he is looking for both class.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi the first query is different, if you cant find the difference ask me, instead of downvoting

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT prof.name FROM professor AS prof    
JOIN works     
ON prof.empid = works.empid    
WHERE works.classid IN (9, 10);
```